# C# lambda expression in the loop

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

[image]

why the varialbe is 2 in the loop?

and it is the 1st breakpoint the program meet in the loop.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code, post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Because by the time your breakpoint was hit in the new thread, the main thread had already looped twice.  Remember, they're running on separate threads, so unless you use some kind of synchronization mechanism, you won't be able to predict what occurs when.

Comment: thank you,and as if the phenomenon seems to relate to closure?